# Prestashop 1.7 video autoplay on home page

Tags: video, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, autoplay

i cant make my video autoplay on my homepage - using free html box with codes below, text box giving me error 505 when i try to save it with youtube code.

```
<iframe width="1110" height="624" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWyB2_8N4M8?controls=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay=1; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

and this not working too

```
<iframe width="1110" height="624" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWyB2_8N4M8?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Prestashop 1.7 - page: http://warhouse.cz/

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the Shop Parameters -> General if you have these settings:

- "Allow iframes on HTML fields" set to Yes;
- "Use HTMLPurifier Library" set to No.

Comment: missed allow iframes option - great thanks! after celaring chrome cache its working now BUT do you know how to implement loop function? i dont want to show random video suggestions after this video ends .. my code now    `<iframe width="1110" height="624" id="ytplayer" type="text/html" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWyB2_8N4M8?autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&controls=0&fs=0&loop=1&modestbranding=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>`

Comment: I think you need to create a playlist and add it as a parameter to your src, e.g. &playlist=GRonxog5mbw where GRonxog5mbw is your playlist

Comment: if my answer regarding your initial question helped please mark it as accepted so others looking for the same might find it.

Comment: Also add trick for responsive iframe video https://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/